# What is the order of execution for the final approval actions in a standard approval process?

Tags: field-update, email-alert, approval-process, order-of-execution

I have 5 field updates and an email alert happening after an opportunity record receives final approval (see image below).

**Will they be executed in the specific order they are listed? If not, what is the order of execution?** Any documentation is helpful.

[image: final approval actions for standard approval process]

*Setting the table further, I need the email alert to execute *after* all of the field updates have processed. The email alert's email template has a merge field that depends on the "Set Stage to Approved" field update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will not be guaranteed to fire in the order you see listed, however this will still work out for you.

In [Considerations for Field Update Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workflow_field_update_considerations.htm&type=5) that covers creating field updates for workflow rules or approval process:

> **Field updates occur before email alerts**, tasks, and outbound messages.
>
> The result of a field update is unpredictable when a single workflow
> rule includes multiple field updates that apply different values to
> the same field

As such, you should be all set to have the email alert be expected to occur after the field updates.